# Why does setting the /pgfplots/variable key interfere with the /tikz/variable key?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, variable

I need to set `/pfgplots/variable` because I have a lot of plots generated using `gnuplot` in my document. But, when I set `/pfgplots/variable={t}`, it breaks the `plot` macro in regular `pgf`. The MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,variable=t}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[line width=2pt, blue] 
        plot [domain=0:2*pi, samples=100] (\x/3,{sin(\x r)});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

does not compile, but

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[line width=2pt, blue] 
        plot [domain=0:2*pi, samples=100] (\x/3,{sin(\x r)});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

does, and so does

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,variable=t}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[line width=2pt, blue] 
        plot [domain=0:2*pi, samples=100, variable=\x] (\x/3,{sin(\x r)});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Are `/pgfplots/variable` and `/tikz/variable` the same keys?

I am trying to address [this issue](https://github.com/rlkamalapurkar/bodeplot/issues/3#issue-1056228551) in a [new package](https://ctan.org/pkg/bodeplot?lang=en) I wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to `...texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots` and do a bit of scavenging with `grep variable *.tex`, you will find in `pgfplots.code.tex`, around line 2338:

```latex
...
/pgfplots/variable/.code={\pgfkeysalso{/tikz/variable={#1}}},
...
```

so yes, they seem tied together (in the sense that setting `/pgfplots/variable` will set also `/tikz/variable`).

About your problem in the package, can't you set `variable=t` only locally?

Comment: For everyone passing by, there is a shorter way to write this: `/pgfplots/variable/.style={/tikz/variable={#1}}`

Comment: @HenriMenke Is there a slight performance advantage in the `.code` approach? It's the only obvious reason for using it

Comment: @JosephWright I doubt it. In fact, `/.style={#1}` is implemented as `/.code={\pgfkeysalso{#1}}`. Probably Christian was just confused when this was written.

Comment: @HenriMenke That means one fewer expansion, so there will be a speedup

Comment: I plan to update the package where it is set locally, I just wanted to know whether the two were linked, and now I do :-). Thank you for investigating!

That does beg the question why, though. Why are those two keys linked? Do they need to be?

Comment: I do not know anything about the inner workings of  the `pgfplots` package, but since `/tikz/variable` expects a macro and `/pgfplots/variable` does not, it seems odd to pass on a potentially non-macro argument to a key that expects a macro argument.